# Capture Source (From Google Ads) In the Form

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, tracking, forms

I have a client who wants to know (based on an actual form submission) when a client came from a Google Ad conversion. I have everything wired up properly (GA4 > Google Tags > Google Ads) so that I'm properly recording the conversions. That's not the issue. The client would like to know, "If John Does submits the form, can you automatically record in your form that they came from a Google Ad so we know how he found us?"

Is it possible to capture this in some fashion? I don't see anything obvious (URL parameters or other data) and, of course, if a person leaves and comes back later in the life of the campaign, they may submit a different form on the website (e.g. main contact form).